# Birkhoff's theorem for hypergraphs

Tags: linear-algebra, hypergraph, matching-theory

[Birkhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff_algorithm) says that, in a bipartite graph $G$ in which both sides have size $n$, any fractional matching of size $n$ can be presented as a convex combination of integral matchings of size $n$ (at most $n^2-2 n +2$ such matchings are needed).

Consider a tripartite hypergraph $H$ in which all three sides have size $n$. In contrast to the bipartite case, a fractional matching of size $n$ does not imply the existence of an integral matching of size $n$, so a direct generalization of Birkhoff's algorithm is not true. Is there a weaker theorem that holds in the case of tripartite hypergraphs? For example, is it true that a fractional matching of size $n$ can be decomposed into integral matchings of size smaller than $n$?

Comment: Sounds like Problem 2 of https://imc-math.org.uk/imc2011/imc2011-day2-solutions.pdf Also, there's a discussion of Hall's Theorem for hypergraphs at https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2012/11/25/happy-birthday-ron-aharoni/

Comment: @GerryMyerson Interesting, but this is about finding a single perfect matching - not about decomposition into a convex combination of perfect matchings.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant: Aharoni and Haxell, "Hall's Theorem for Hypergraphs," http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~whalen/Papers/Hall/matchingsinhyps.pdf